# Spark application with Jetty embedded server is not logging bubbled exceptions

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, spark-java

It's a really basic setup, I am using slf4j-simple

I have the following route:

```
    get("/fail", (req, res) -> {
                throw new RuntimeException("fail");
            }
    );
```

As expected, it throws 500 internal error.

However, the logs show nothing about this. How can I get these bubbled exceptions to log?

These are the only logs I see:

```
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @164ms
[Thread-0] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - == Spark has ignited ...
[Thread-0] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@35eae602{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4567}
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @259ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You may implement your log operation inside the [Exception Mapper](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#exception-mapping).